# Unacceptable quality of writing in a letter of recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter, writing-style

I have received a letter of recommendation which clearly has been written by my referee's assistant, rather than himself. That in itself wouldn't be a problem if it didn't contain phrases such as *what's more...* and *like event study etc*.

What should I do about this? Do I just forget about the reference? Do I very carefully suggest to the assistant to make some minor changes (this letter is based on a previous draft I was asked to submit)?

It may also be worth noting that the referee is the first supervisor for my thesis and I do not want to seem ungrateful by requesting changes to my letter of recommendation.

It seems to me that the use of the phrase *what's more* in a letter of recommendation is per se unacceptable, but my native language is German, so any comments by native speakers of English in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: If you're applying for something in the US, you should never see your own recommendation letters.

Comment: @JeffE What do you mean by this? It should go straight from referee to the receiver? Or you should receive it and not look at it, else it will create unnecessary stress?

Comment: What do you mean by your "referee?" Is this a role different from or in addition to being your thesis adviser? Is the letter signed by the assistant, or by the supervisor? It probably matters whether you're in the US or Europe. My understanding is that European letters are usually very brief and rely on the prestige of the recommender, whereas US letters are fulsome odes of praise. In the US system, I don't think a strong letter written in bad English would be discounted if it was being read by people who knew the writer by reputation and knew that his/her native language was Hungarian.

Comment: The letter is signed by my supervisor, whose role is to assess or certify my aptitude for postgraduate studies. As such, the letter relies both on the reputation of the referee and the assessment of my academic strengths, although it is unlikely that the referee is known by name. In this sense, I cannot confirm your description of the European practice entirely. In this particular case the native language is German. Based on my previous experience of the referee, I can say with certainty that this letter was written in its entirety by his assistant.

Comment: @JeffE if the author of the reference letter wants to share it with OP, it's his decision.

Comment: Note that "what's more" is not in itself an error or particularly casual: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/what-s-more Of course the letter might not use it appropriately: you've seen it and I haven't, so your call whether to request correction.

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge Recommenders send their letters directly to your target departments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would certainly request a corrected version. Like you said, in a careful measure, I would keep the tone of the message somewhere along the lines "some minor mistakes, happens to all of us, but these little changes go a long way in credibility of the letter". In other words, don't criticize, put together a list of things you want corrected and send them to the referee. I deduce from your question that the letter was proxy-written, i.e. you haven't been told that it was the assistant who wrote it. That's why I'm recommending to contact the referee and not the assistant. However, if that is not the case, include both of them.

I can't see why someone other than an extreme ego-maniac would choose not to correct their own grammar mistakes. Even it they for whatever reason do, it's still better than just to "forget about the reference".

Answer (score 1):

Start in an e-mail to the referencer "Dear Dr. X, Thank-you ever so much for the reference letter." If there was something nice brought up in it like "Constantin was an excellent student", thank them for the kind words while citing the letter. Then, after you say your thanks, bring up the minor errors (don't list them exhaustively) asking if they could correct them, please. Thank them for their time in reading your e-mail.

If they can't correct it, say thanks. If they can correct it, say thanks and that you really appreciate them taking time out of their busy day.

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify, there don't seem to be any grammatical mistakes in the letter. Rather, it uses simple, almost naive and inappropriately casual style ( for example, the letter describes the methodology I used in an event study simply as *event study etc.*). This is much harder to bring up. The general tone of the letter is however very positive.

Comment: @Constantin Oh, that. Yes, I've had recommendation letters like that too. They aren't too uncommon from professors and the like. Long story, I won't delve into theories on why this is.

If you need the recommendation letter to stand by itself, just thank the individual and after doing so say "because this is the main piece, do you mind adding a bit more detail to X, Y, and Z so that the reader has a better grasp on it".

Comment: @Constantin If this is one letter of a few or is accompanied by something written by you further describing your work (CV or Cover Letter with attached references) and unless the quality is very bad, you should be content with the letter as it is. Writing a proper/great letter of recommendation is difficult after all. If they go into details, they risk running three times as long as you need. If they try to be brief, a letter possibly like yours arises.